# Is that possible to control cl.exe option in source file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to compile the unit with /EHsc option, how could i set this option in source file for msvc?

thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, too bad the answer's going to be a negative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set compiler options inside the same source file you are compiling -- in the general case, the compiler needs to be configured *before* it starts processing it.

What you can do it set compiler options by consuming a [command file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2khzsa1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and set compiler options per file using the solution's project file.